# Understanding the below clauses in match recognize

Tags: oracle, match-recognize

This question is already answered but I could not get few parts of the query. Below is the input table.

```
ID  NAME    DISEASE DRUG    SHIP_DATE   SUPPLY
1   aa        D1    dd      10-05-2020  30
1   aa        D1    dd      07-06-2020  30
1   aa        D1    dd      12-07-2020  30
1   aa        D1    dd      09-08-2020  30
1   aa        D1    dd      07-09-2020  28
1   aa        D1    dd      11-10-2020  28
1   aa        D1    dd      10-11-2020  28
2   bb        D2    cd      01-01-2020  10
2   bb        D2    cd      06-01-2020  10
```

My requirement was to get whether next order(ship date) is early or late.
e.g- First order is on 10-05-2020 + supply(30) = 09-06-2020( next expected date) but the patient ordered on 07-06-2020 so second order is **Early order** case. Now, 07-06-2020+supply(30)= 09-07-2020(expected date) but patient ordered on 12-07-2020.Third order  is **Late Order** Case.

If Order is **early** then next expected date is **ship date + suppy** but if order is **late** then next expected date is **previous expected date + supply**.(op will make it better to understand)

```
ID NAME DISEASE DRUG SHIP_DATE      SUPPLY EXP_DATE   LATE_OR_EARLY GAP
-- ---- ------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---
 1 aa   D1      dd   10-05-2020         30            first order      
 1 aa   D1      dd   07-06-2020         30 09-06-2020 early            
 1 aa   D1      dd   12-07-2020         30 09-07-2020 late            3
 1 aa   D1      dd   09-08-2020         30 11-08-2020 early            
 1 aa   D1      dd   07-09-2020         28 10-09-2020 early            
 1 aa   D1      dd   11-10-2020         28 08-10-2020 late            3
 1 aa   D1      dd   10-11-2020         28 08-11-2020 late            2
 2 bb   D2      cd   01-01-2020         10            first order      
 2 bb   D2      cd   06-01-2020         10 11-01-2020 early
```

Below is the query I got from Stack Overflow:

```
1. with   prep (id, name, disease, drug, ship_date, supply, e_date,
    cls, exp_date) as (
        select id, name, disease, drug, ship_date, supply, e_date, cls,
               case cls when 'A' then lag(e_date + supply) 
                                        over (partition by id, disease, drug
                                              order     by ship_date)
                        else e_date end as exp_date
        from   input_table
        match_recognize(
          partition by id, disease, drug
          order     by ship_date
          measures  a.ship_date + sum(supply) - supply as e_date,
                    classifier() as cls
          all rows per match
          pattern   (a b*)
          define    b as ship_date <= a.ship_date + sum(supply) - supply
        )   ) select id, name, disease, drug, ship_date, supply, exp_date,
           case when exp_date is null then 'first order'
                when cls = 'A'        then 'late'
                else                       'early' end     as late_or_early,
           case cls when 'A' then ship_date - exp_date end as gap from   prep order  by id, disease, drug, ship_date ;
```

What is the pattern and define clause actually doing here and how is it calculating the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern   (a b*)
```

Matches one row as `a` and then zero-or-more rows as `b`

```
define    b as ship_date <= a.ship_date + sum(supply) - supply
```

- `a` is not defined so it will match any single row.
- `b` is defined such that the `ship_date` of the current row being matched is less-than-or-equal-to `<=` the `ship_date` of the `a` row plus `+` the `sum` of the `supply` (in, since it is an aggregation function, all the `a` and `b` rows in the current match) minus `-` the `supply` of the current row being matched.

---

For your data:

```
ID NAME DISEASE DRUG SHIP_DATE      SUPPLY EXP_DATE   LATE_OR_EARLY GAP
-- ---- ------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ---
 1 aa   D1      dd   10-05-2020         30            first order      
 1 aa   D1      dd   07-06-2020         30 09-06-2020 early            
 1 aa   D1      dd   12-07-2020         30 09-07-2020 late            3
```

- The first row of the partition will always match the `a` pattern.
- The second row checks if `2020-06-07` is less than or equal to `2020-05-10` plus `SUM(30, 30)` (total of all the supplies in the current match) minus `30` (current supply) which totals `2020-06-09`. Since this true then the row is a `b` row.
- The third row checks if `2020-07-12`  is less than or equal to `2020-05-10` plus `SUM(30, 30, 30)` (total of all the supplies in the current match) minus `30` (current supply) which totals `2020-07-09`. Since this false then the row is not included in the previous pattern and starts a new matching group as the `a` row.